# On skyrim I want to find more of the unusual gem but I can't

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to find all of the unusual gems for the thieves guild but I can't find any, I only have 3, are they in dungeons or where?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go talk to Vex in the Ragged Flagon and then become a full member of the Thieves' Guild before going any further.

They're called the Stones of Barenziah, because they were once part of the crown of Barenziah, the Queen of Morrowind during the course of the events of TES3: Morrowind and its DLC. Read about her in the "Biography of Barenziah" books occasionally found on bookshelves. There are 24 in all. Here's a list of their locations:
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Stones_of_Barenziah

(I would copy the list here, but that seems like blatant plagiarism and it would make for an extremely long answer anyway.)